# How Run Xaml Animation With C# Code

Tags: wpf

I Have Animation In My ResourceDictionary But I Want Call Animation In My C# Code.
This ResourceDictionary  Add To My Resources App

Example:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<BeginStoryboard x:Key="PuzzleFall">
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="RenderT" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Duration="0:0:3" BeginTime="0:0:0">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeySpline="1 0,0.95 0" KeyTime="0:0:3"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:3.06" Duration="0:0:1.5">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="50" KeySpline="0 1,0 1" KeyTime="0:0:1.5"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:3.08" Duration="0:0:1">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeySpline="1 0,1 0" KeyTime="0:0:1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:4.1" Duration="0:0:1">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="15" KeySpline="0 1,0 1" KeyTime="0:0:1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:4.15" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeySpline="1 0,1 0" KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>

</BeginStoryboard>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I Want Run This Animation In C# Code.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/afc450c7-3467-457e-80bf-ed1b8adea9ec) thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should not put the `Storyboard` which is the main component inside a `BeginStoryboard` especially if you use code. EIther way. you can get the Storyboard using `FindResource`.

In your current setup something like this:

```
var beginsb = (BeginStoryboard)FindResource("PuzzleFall");
var sb = beginsb.Storyboard;
sb.Begin();
```